Where to give away Judaic books, etc
Are there websites or organizations that find new homes for Judaic books, both Hebrew and English, and other Judaica such as tefillin?

There are numerous websites that stock second-hand used Seforim:
Jewish Used Books
New and Used Seforim
Seforim World in Brooklyn, NYC (16th Ave)
As far as Judaica check out Judaica On Demand, also
In addition, there might also be someone locally to you that sells second-hand seforim (we have several here in London). Similarly, there might be someone that maintains a seforim / judaica gemach, with readily accessible items.

Do any of these places accept used seforim, either as donations buying them?

You would have to contact them and ask?
